# Toast makes my application crash

Tags: java, android

When i use Toast my application crash and i face this error!

```
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class TextView
```

Comment: please add code and xml

Comment: @chornge theres no textview in my layout!

Comment: Whats the relation between a Toast and the textView? my app runs when i delete that  Toast line